# A list of random doubles within defined range in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, random

How can I make a list of random numbers of type 'Double', that fit within a defined range? Info on this matter for a newbie like me is a little bit confusing. Trying something like:

```
randomlist :: Int -> Int -> [IO Double]
randomlist a b = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return (randomRs (a,b) g)
```

fails, with error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `IO StdGen'
```

Could you point to mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost have it.  You have two problems.  The main problem is the `[IO Double]` part of your type signature; this says you'll be returning a list of IO actions, each of which can produce a double.  Instead, you want to return an `IO [Double]`—an IO action which, when run, produces an infinite list of doubles.  If you just change that, you're almost done; the remaining issue is that you have `a` and `b` as `Int`s, but return `Double`s.  If you want to return doubles, your bounds need to be doubles, and similarly for integers.  (To convert `Int`s to `Double`s, you can use `fromIntegral`; to go the other way, you can use `round`.)  Thus, to get your code working, all you need to change is the type signature:

```
randomlist :: Double -> Double -> IO [Double]
randomlist a b = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return (randomRs (a,b) g)
```

And in fact, if you'd left off the type signature, everything would have been fine; GHC would have inferred the more general type signature `Random a => a -> a -> IO [a]`.  In other words, your function works with any data type you can generate random members of.

You can also simplify your code slightly.  The following, for instance, is equivalent:

```
randomlist :: Random a => a -> a -> IO [a]
randomlist a b = fmap (randomRs (a,b)) newStdGen
```

The `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` function allows you to apply an ordinary function *inside* a functor.  What's a functor?  Roughly speaking, it's some sort of container; type functions such as `[]`, `(r ->)`, and `IO` are examples.<sup>1</sup>  This is exactly what you want; `randomRs (a,b)` has type `(Random a, RandomGen g) => g -> [a]`, and you instead need to give it something of type `IO StdGen`, getting a `Random a => IO [a]` back.

There's one more way you can make this nicer (and this is the way I'd write it).  If you import `Control.Applicative`, you end up with

```
import Control.Applicative
randomlist :: Random a => a -> a -> IO [a]
randomlist a b = randomRs (a,b) <$> newStdGen
```

`<$>` is a synonym for `fmap`; it looks like `$`, ordinary application, because they're *almost* the same.  `<$>` just lifts you into a functor (here, `IO`).

---

**1:** Don't worry if this isn't perfectly clear; you can get away with using this stuff without understanding it in full detail, which will eventually lead to understanding.

Comment: Or: `randomlist a b = newStdGen >>= randomRs (a, b)`

Comment: @monadic No, that doesn't typecheck.

Comment: @dave4420 It typechecks if you write `randomlist a b = newStdGen >>= return . randomRs (a, b)` instead.

Comment: @dave4420 Add a `return`. You can also write - quite pointless - `randomlist = (((<$> newStdGen) . randomRs) .) . (,)`.

Comment: @FUZxxl Ahh sorry, didn't know the type of randomRs. Although I should have noticed since its being used applicatively...

Answer (score 7):

The main mistake is in your type signature. Removing it and asking `ghci` what the inferred type is gives this:

```
*Main> :t randomlist
randomlist :: Random a => a -> a -> IO [a]
```

Of course, you may constrain this to the type `Double -> Double -> IO [Double]` if you wish, and you can add some calls to `fromIntegral` if you want to restrict further to integer bounds:

```
randomlist :: Int -> Int -> IO [Double]
randomlist a b = do
    g <- newStdGen
    return (randomRs (fromIntegral a, fromIntegral b) g)
```

---

Note the difference between the type `[IO Double]` and `IO [Double]`. The former is a list of computations returning `Double`, while the latter is a single computation returning a list of `Double`, which is what you want in this case.

The error message may be a bit cryptic, but it's basically telling you that because `newStdGen` has the type `IO StdGen`, the bind `<-` is only allowed when the type of the `do`-expression is an `IO something`, whereas your type signature says the type should be `[something]`.